# Push Notification working only on one device (android)

Tags: c#, android, azure, notifications, push-notification

I am developing for android on Xamarin (c#), I followed this guide to setup a notification system with Microsoft azure : 
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/partner-xamarin-notification-hubs-android-get-started/#register

The thing is that then I tested on both of my devices only one received the notification, and for some reason on the azure hub server I see only one registered device, I thought maybe be there is a problem with my other phone and even tried to install the application on my friend phone and it didn't work either .

I will not post any code here because its exactly like in the guide I posted just with my information (google id, and hub name and so on..)

The first phone (on this one the notification works) is running version 4.2.2, and having a root premonitions if it make any difference.

The second phone (not working) is running version 4.4.2.

Any ideas or suggestions ? Thank's in advance.

Comment: Are you getting a registration ID from GCM on both devices?  Are you getting a registration ID back from the Hub after you register on both devices?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I solved the problem and you were right the hub didn't register the devices the reason for this was that I called the registration with if that checked if the device support notifications and I didn't it wrong. putting a break point and debugging helped to figure this.